# Grunt Watch forever using Grunt Forever

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

According to the grunt-forever documentation, grunt-forever must point to an application file. I just want to perform the grunt-watch task so that I can continuously watch a file, forever, and perform tasks if this file ever changes.

Is this possible with grunt forever?

If so, what would the config file look like?